# Persistent rainbow test pattern

Tags: gpu

I've got an install of arch linux on my B+, but the test pattern is showing in the upper-right corner of the screen even well after the OS is fully booted.  It disappears every now and then, but comes back when I take any action.  I think it is getting re-drawn whenever there is activity on the GPU.  I've looked through tons of documentation on config.txt hoping to find a solution, but to no avail.  Has anyone else seen this issue?  Is there anyway to get rid of it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Raspberry Pi.SE Is this pattern showing up on the command line or in X?

Comment: @goldilocks I don't think the archlinux tag is appropriate, the problem doesn't relate to arch itself and could present in any OS

Comment: You're right.  It wasn't actually me that added that (I just put "rainbow" in the title"), but I've removed it.  You can rollback/change edits other people have made to your own question, BTW.  You can see the revisions in order by clicking on the "edited ___ ago".

Comment: Couldn't know that by then... BTW "test pattern" is also misleading.

Comment: @goldilocks so sorry, i though i saw you in the edit history there, i'm cool with your edit, actually.  I'm aware of how to check revisions, apparently i just didn't look closely enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like one of two warnings.

1. red square over temperature (>85 C)
2. rainbow square power supply under voltage (<4.65V)

See http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=82373 for fuller details.

Comment: Thanks, it's the rainbow square, I was powering it from a USB port on a sleeping/hibernating computer.  I feel like this should be documented at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md

Comment: The Foundation is a little lame WRT documentation, unfortunately.   I think the most exhaustive, organized source is [their github site](https://github.com/raspberrypi).  If you click through to "documention" you can do word based searches at the top.  I don't think this is anywhere there, though.

Comment: @goldilocks Unfortunately that appears to be true.  elinux *tends* to be more accurate than the raspberrypi.org  documentation.  Perhaps because it's easier to edit on elinux.

Answer (score 1):

I get the under-voltage (rainbow) when running quite a few of the full screen pi3d demos whenever there's quite a bit going on. The cpu monitor is down less than 10% and it seems to do it with or without the x server running. The power supply is a good quality USB and I've never had any other under-voltage problems.

However you can disable it if you really want (as per @joan's link)